# SQL Server 2008 R2 restore database and users into instance security area

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When I do a restore from a `.bak` file, everything works as expected including the users appearing under the `DB > Security > Users` area.

What is the best way to also make these users appear under the main instance `> security > Logins`?

Comment: Those are two totally separate things: a `User` is a per-database object and it will be backed up with the normal database backup into your `.bak` file. `Login` is a **per-server** object and is **NOT** included in your normal backup process - you need to handle that separately, since it's a **server object** - not a database-level object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to use code to re-create the logins before. This is quite common in SQL server.  The problem with auto-creating the users is that their passwords no longer exist. But, as long as you can give them new passwords, you should be able to do the following (fill user, login, and password):

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'userName', NULL, 'password'
```

Source:
http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/sql_orphan_user.htm

Comment: Thank you for your post.  There was an alteration to your proc that was neccesary.  The correct syntax is EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'userName', NULL, 'password'

Comment: Yes, I suppose that was a given since the login did not exist.